# where is RETICULATE_PYTHON loaded from

Tags: r, reticulate

Every time I start RStudio, the wrong value is loaded. I'd like to change the value from a `conda` path to a regular python path.

```
> Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON")
[1] "C:/wrong/anaconda/path"
```

Meaning I have to manually set this envvar

```
Sys.setenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON" = "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe")
```

I have no idea where the initial value comes from. I checked for `.Rprofile` or `.Renviron` files in

```
path.expand("~")
R.home()
getwd()
```

But none exist... On the Windows command prompt, there is no such variable (`SET R` only shows `RTOOLS40_HOME`)

Comment: Have you tried `usethis::edit_r_environ()` and `usethis::edit_r_profile()` ?

Comment: looks like this creates files, but it doesn't tell me where the initial config is loaded from..

Comment: Have you looked at the environment variables set in your user account in the windows control panel?

Comment: I checked the envvars both user and system yeah